# Curiosity : An inequality involving logarithms

Tags: reference-request, inequality

Does exists $\alpha \in R $ and a positive constant  C such that

$\displaystyle{%
\left[\,x\ln\left(\, x\,\right) - x\,\right]
-\left[\, y\ln\left(\, y\,\right) - y\,\right]\
\leq\
C\,\left\vert\, x - y\,\right\vert^{\alpha}\,,\quad\mbox{for}\ x,y\ > 0\ \mbox{?.}}
$

If yes, do you know an analytical proof ?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think so. Consider a fixed $y$. The RHS needs to be pointy when $x=y$, so $\alpha\le 1$. But we already know that $x\ln(x)-x-(y\ln(y)-y)\in O(x\ln(x))$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: You are asking about Holder continuity of $f(x) = x\ln x - x$. This is uninteresting away from 0; near 0 we would need $x\ln x - x \le C x^\alpha$, or $\ln x - 1 \le C x^{\alpha-1}$. What is the behavior of $\ln x$ for $x$ near 0?

Comment: but I am interessed for all $x,y > 0$ ...

Comment: As ln grows slowly when the argument is high, the only problem comes near $0$

Comment: @RossMilikan, do you know a proof near zero ?

Comment: from wolfram alpha it appears that : $2x^{10} -xln(x) +x \geq 0$ for all $x > 0$,that is, $xlnx - x \leq 2 x^{10}$

Comment: @RossMillikan No, it already fails when you consider $y=2$ for example. See my first comment. Just plot the graph out, and it will be obvious why.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

There is no such $\alpha$. Indeed, assume the converse. Fix $y=1$ and let $x\to\infty$. Then we obtain $\alpha>1$. From the other side, put $x_n=e^{-2n}$, $y_n=e^{-n}$, for each $n$. Then 
$$|x_n-y_n|^\alpha=e^{-n\alpha}+o(e^{-n\alpha}).$$

$$x\ln x – x - y\ln y+y=-2ne^{-2n}-e^{-2n}+ne^{-n}+e^{-n}=ne^{-n}+o(ne^{-n}).$$

Then we obtain $\alpha<1$, a contradiction.